# Axios rewrites Authorization header

Tags: vue.js, axios

I am new in vuejs. Developing on Laravel8 + Vuejs3.
I have following code in vue:

```
methods: {
   getUsersList(url=null){
            let request_headers = {}
            request_headers['Accept'] = 'application/json'
            if(this.$store.state.token !== null) {
                request_headers['Authorization'] = 'Bearer ' + ' ' + this.$store.state.token
            }
            if(url == null) {
                url = this.API_URL + '/user/list'
            }
            axios
            .get(url, {headers: request_headers})
            .then(response => {
                if(response.data.result){
                    this.headers = response.data.data.headers;
                    this.body = response.data.data.body;
                }
            })}
```

`console.log(request_headers['Authorization'])` shows right token, but in request headers axios sends another token(all the time the same)

I don't know why. Please help. I tried a few solution like: creating new axios instance and adding default header manually

Helpless.

Comment: Follow this [set axios headers](https://masteringjs.io/tutorials/axios/headers) Or create an instance by creating [interceptor way](https://masteringjs.io/tutorials/axios/interceptors) - dont be frightened, its very easy

Comment: I added axios.interceptors.request.use(req => {
                req.headers.authorization = `Bearer ${this.$store.state.token}`
                return req;
            }); - BUT it does not work

Comment: ${this.$store.state.token}  return proper store token ?